# Are these pointwise cofibrant cosimplicial objects cofibrant in the Reedy model structure?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

Suppose I have a Quillen pair $F \dashv G$ with $F:\text{Psh}(\mathcal{C}\times{\Delta}) \to \mathcal{M},$  and consider also the category of cosimplicial objects in $\mathcal{M}$ denoted $\mathcal{M}^{\Delta}$ where we have the Reedy model structure. Let $h_{(C,n)}$ be a representable functor in $\text{Psh}(\mathcal{C}\times{\Delta})$.

> How do I prove that the cosimplicial object $\Gamma C:n \mapsto Fh_{(C,n)}$ is cofibrant in $\mathcal{M}^{\Delta}$?

It would suffice to prove that $L_nFh_{(C,n)}\to Fh_{(C,n)}$ is a cofibration in $\mathcal{M}$ for every $n.$

> But how do I compute the latching space $$L_nFh_{(C,n)}=\text{colim}_{m
>  \to n}Fh_{(C,m)}=F(\text{colim}_{m\to n}h_{(C,m)})?$$

where the index of the colimit I recall is the category of maps $\textbf{m} \to \textbf{n}$ for $m<n$.

Maybe $$\text{colim}_{m\to n}h_{(C,n)}=\text{colim}_{m\to n}(h_{C}\times h_n)=h_C \times \text{colim}_{m\to n}h_n=h_C\times \partial\Delta^n$$ and $$h_C \times \partial \Delta^n \to h_C \times h_n$$ is a cofibration?

Comment: What's the model structure you're using on simplicial presheaves here? Injective? Projective? Something else?

Comment: Based on your other questions, I'm assuming projective model structure.

Comment: In that case, taking a simplicial set $K$ to $h_C\times K$ is left quillen, since it's left adjoint to evaluation at $C$, which is right quillen by definition of the projective model structure.

Comment: Therefore yes, the map at the end is a cofibration.

Comment: @jgon Yes, it was the projective. Thanks!

Comment: @jgon How would you prove that $h_C \times (-)$ is left quillen? $h_C$ is the presheaf taking $C'$ to the constant simplicial set which has $\text{Hom}(C',C)$ in every degree. I am having problems showing the adjunction with evaluation at $C.$ see also the comments here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814734/representable-functors-are-cofibrant

Comment: I've added an answer proving the adjunction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in the comments, given the work in the question, it suffices to prove that the functor $\newcommand\op{{\text{op}}}\newcommand\C{\mathcal{C}}h_C\times - : \newcommand\sSet{\mathbf{sSet}}\sSet\to [\C^\op,\sSet]$ is left Quillen. In turn, it suffices to prove that this functor is left adjoint to $\newcommand\ev{\operatorname{ev}}\ev_C : [\C^\op,\sSet]\to\sSet$, since this functor is right Quillen by definition of the projective model structure.

You've asked in the comments about how to prove that these functors are in fact adjoint, so that's what I will address in this answer. I'm going to use the convention that lowercase $c$s are objects in the category $\C$.

I think this is easier using ends to unpack and repack natural transformations. A quite extensive reference on the topic of (co)ends is [Fosco Loregian's Co/end calculus](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.02503).
$$
\newcommand\Set{\mathbf{Set}}
\begin{align*}
[\C^\op,\sSet](h_c\times K,F) 
&\simeq \int_{c'\in\C^\op}\sSet(h_c(c')\times K,Fc')
\\
&\simeq \int_{c'\in\C^\op}\int_{n\in\Delta^\op}
\Set(h_c(c')\times K_n,F(c',n))
\\
&\simeq
\int_{n\in\Delta^\op}
\int_{c'\in\C^\op}
\Set(K_n,\Set(h_c(c'),F(c',n)))
\\
&\simeq
\int_{n\in\Delta^\op}
\Set\left(K_n,\int_{c'\in\C^\op}\Set(h_c(c'),F(c',n))\right)
\\
&\simeq
\int_{n\in\Delta^\op}
\Set\left(K_n,F(c,n)\right)
\\
&\simeq
\sSet\left(K,Fc\right)
\\
\end{align*}
$$

However, a direct proof may also be given, at the cost of essentially reproving the Yoneda lemma.

Given a natural transformation $\alpha : h_c\times K\to F$, we can consider the component $\alpha_c : h_c(c)\times K\to Fc$, and then restrict this to $1_c\times K \cong K \to Fc$, producing a map of simplicial sets from $K$ to $Fc$.

Conversely, given $a : K\to Fc$, for each $f:c'\to c$, define $\alpha_f : K\to Fc'$ by $\alpha_f = f^* \circ a$. Then define $\alpha_{c'} : h_c(c')\times K \to Fc'$ to be $\alpha_f$ on the component $f\times K$. You can check that this defines a natural transformation $\alpha : h_c\times K \to F$, and that these procedures give a bijection between natural transformations $h_c\times K \to F$ and maps of simplicial sets $K\to Fc$, as desired.